# Why there is no gemspec in some gems

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

why there is no `.gemspec` file in some gems, eg. `rspec` or `rspec-rails`, if there is no `.gemspec` file, how did the gem build ?

thanks!

Comment: There are `.gemspec` files in both those gems. See for example https://github.com/rspec/rspec .

Comment: ok, it's not in packaged gem, i opened it by 'bundle open'. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.gemspec` is needed to build the gem, but not to use it. Why would it be in the gem? The spec is already contained in the gem's metadata, why duplicate it?

```
gem spec rspec
# --- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification
# name: rspec
# version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#   version: 3.0.0
# platform: ruby
# authors:
# - Steven Baker
# - David Chelimsky
# - Myron Marston
# autorequire: 
# bindir: bin
# cert_chain: []
# date: 2014-06-02 00:00:00.000000000 Z
# dependencies:
# - !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
#   name: rspec-core
#   requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#     requirements:
#     - - "~>"
#       - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#         version: 3.0.0
#   type: :runtime
#   prerelease: false
#   version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#     requirements:
#     - - "~>"
#       - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#         version: 3.0.0
# - !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
#   name: rspec-expectations
#   requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#     requirements:
#     - - "~>"
#       - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#         version: 3.0.0
#   type: :runtime
#   prerelease: false
#   version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#     requirements:
#     - - "~>"
#       - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#         version: 3.0.0
# - !ruby/object:Gem::Dependency
#   name: rspec-mocks
#   requirement: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#     requirements:
#     - - "~>"
#       - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#         version: 3.0.0
#   type: :runtime
#   prerelease: false
#   version_requirements: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#     requirements:
#     - - "~>"
#       - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#         version: 3.0.0
# description: BDD for Ruby
# email: rspec@googlegroups.com
# executables: []
# extensions: []
# extra_rdoc_files: []
# files: []
# homepage: http://github.com/rspec
# licenses: []
# metadata: 
# post_install_message: 
# rdoc_options: []
# require_paths:
# - lib
# required_ruby_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#   requirements:
#   - - ">="
#     - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#       version: '0'
# required_rubygems_version: !ruby/object:Gem::Requirement
#   requirements:
#   - - ">="
#     - !ruby/object:Gem::Version
#       version: '0'
# requirements: []
# rubyforge_project: rspec
# rubygems_version: 2.2.2
# signing_key: 
# specification_version: 4
# summary: rspec-3.0.0
# test_files: []
# has_rdoc: true
```

Comment: so where these metadata information stored ? there is a gemspec file in github.com/rspec repository, but not in gem sources

Comment: It's stored in the Gem. You'll have to look at the sourcecode of RubyGems or the specification of the Gem file format if you want to know where and how exactly. My guess is it's simply stored in a file inside the ZIP.

Comment: do you mean the source code opened by bundle open rspec? i can't find anything about these metadata

Comment: No, I mean the `.gem` file. It contains the data (i.e. the source code) and the metadata (i.e. the gemspec). Some gem authors also put the gemspec source file into the source. I don't know why, that's just duplicate information.

Comment: No, i download the rspec.gem file from rubygems.org and gem unpack rspec.gem, there is no metadata at all

Comment: Of course, there is metadata. If there weren't, then `gem unpack` wouldn't even know how to unpack the gem, after all.

Comment: Obviously somewhere in the `.gem`. You can print out the spec using the `gem spec` command. Like I said before: You'll have to look at the sourcecode of RubyGems or the specification of the Gem file format if you want to know where and how exactly.

Comment: The file format is described in a comment in the sourcecode of the `Gem::Package` class in [`lib/rubygems/package.rb`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/package.rb#L9-L10): "A `.gem` file is a tarball which contains a `data.tar.gz` and `metadata.gz`, and possibly signatures."